# What's the most simple tuple implementation in C++26?

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, c++-templates, c++26

C++26 is seeing some progress in making template parameter packs more ergonomic. For example [P2662: Pack indexing](https://wg21.link/P2662R3) has been accepted into the standard.
With this and other related proposals, what's the most simple `tuple` implementation one could make?

I'm envisioning something along the lines of:

```cpp
template <typename... T>
struct tuple {
    T... m;
};

tuple<int, float> tup{};
float f = tup.m[1];
```

Will it be possible to write something like this? If not exactly with this syntax, then how? If not at all, what proposals are missing to make this happen?

Comment: Where does the standard say `T... m;` is valid as class member declaration?

Comment: @WeijunZhou I believe it doesn't yet, but there I vaguely recall some proposals for C++26 that would make this valid. The code block I've provided is basically pseudo-code.

Comment: OK. I'm interested in what proposal advocates this and whether it has been accepted to C++26, because P2662 alone certainly is not enough to make it valid IMO.

Comment: https://x.com/ericniebler/status/1724228456555114925?s=46&t=8zN_kRC21qGKSNQ6KCn_7g

Comment: It's January 2024. I think it's more than a little premature to ask what the simplest tuple implementation will be in C++26. Also, even if we get member packs. `tup.m[1]` will definitely not be valid syntax to get that `float`.

Comment: @WeijunZhou I think its already accepted [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pack_indexing#top)

Comment: @haleyk I know P2662 is accepted. I'm asking about the `T... m` class member syntax, which I don't think is valid.

Comment: The question shows an analog for `std::get<1>()`. Is `std::get<float>()` intentionally ignored?

Comment: @JaMiT I consider `std::get<float>` a luxury and non-essential for a tuple-implementation. It's also relatively easy to implement once you have `std::get<I>`, namely through the `std::min` of all `I` where `std::get<I>` is same as `float`. This can be done in a single fold-expression or pack expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename ...P>
auto make_my_tuple(P &&... args)
{
    return [...args = std::forward<P>(args)]<std::size_t I> -> auto &&
    {
        return args...[I];
    };
}

int main()
{
    auto t = make_my_tuple(1, 2.2f, 3.3);
    std::cout << t.operator()<1>() << '\n'; // Like `get<1>()`.
}
```

I'm half-joking, obviously. But you could create a template class that wraps such lambdas and gives them a decent interface.

Comment: Such a type wouldn't be reusable though, would it? I.e. you create a new tuple-type each time, and can't generate this from `tuple<int, float>`.

Comment: @JanSchultke Passing the same arguments to `P...` should give you the same type. You can create those from `std::tuple` with `std::apply` (could replace the function with another lambda to make this easier).